# QGIS Print Layout attribute table source as model output

Tags: qgis, table, layouts, printing

I have created a model which extracts features from larger shapefile databases around a site boundary. Each time I run the model I am using a different site boundary, however the outputs have the same name as they pull from the same database.

My goal is to automate the export of a print layout (using the model) with an attribute table for one output/extracted shapefile per print layout. As such, I want the attribute table source to automatically update based on the model output.

How might I go about this?

Currently, the attribute table in the print layout is blank until the source is selected. Obviously I can do this manually by going to each print layout and assigning the source as the corresponding model output, however I want this to happen automatically. Exporting the print layout with correct attribute table as PDF will the last step of the model.

I'm not very familiar with using expressions.